# Codeigniter Biostall Google Map API on tab issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, google-maps

I have tried a lot to show the google map on my tab name Map. But it is showing only blank gray box and no map is shown. But when i am using it directly on page it is working fine. I know there is some issue with `resize()` function. Please provide me a solution how can i solve this using **Biostall Library**. I have given my code below.

**This is my Controller Code:**

```
$config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$config['zoom'] = "18";
$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
// Get the co-ordinates from the database using our model
//$coords = $this->map_model->get_coordinates();
// Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
$marker = array();
$marker['position'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
$marker['infowindow_content'] = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway in Mountain View, Santa Clara County, California';
$marker['icon'] = base_url('assets/img/map-ico.png');
$this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
// Create the map
$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
```

**This is my View code Below**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="map">
  <div class="">
    <?php echo $map['js']; ?>
    <?php echo $map['html']; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check and let me know if you want any more information regarding that.

Waiting for your answers. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** 
Try using the following view it should solve your tab-pane problem. RESULT: http://prntscr.com/g6gu6s

```
<?=$map['js'];?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.container').on('shown.bs.tab',function()
  {google.maps.event.trigger(window,'resize',{});})
  });
</script>

<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#map" id="mapTab" >Map</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    </div>
    <div id="map" class="tab-pane fade">
        <?=$map['html'] ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Previous Answer:** 
Please ensure you have complete each of the following steps.

1. Place both [Googlemaps.php](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlemaps.php) and [Jsmin.php](https://github.com/BIOSTALL/CodeIgniter-Google-Maps-V3-API-Library/blob/master/application/libraries/Jsmin.php) in your
   `application/libraries` folder in CI.
2. Have Generated API key from following Google Link:
   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
   Look for `var $apiKey= ''` in Googlemaps.php and place your newly generated API key
   there.
3. Please also make you have included your library in start of you controller function as well `$this->load->library('googlemaps');`, as currently I can't find it your current controller code.
   ***PS:*** please make sure you have included your url helper in autoload as well, if you don't load it like I did in sample code.
4. Pass your data to your view as well on the last
   `$this->load->view('jsmap', $data);`

Try Following in your Controller:

```
    $this->load->library('googlemaps');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $config['center'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
    $config['zoom'] = "18";
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);
    // Get the co-ordinates from the database using our model
    //$coords = $this->map_model->get_coordinates();
    // Loop through the coordinates we obtained above and add them to the map
    $marker = array();
    $marker['position'] = '37.4419, -122.1419';
    $marker['infowindow_content'] = '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway in Mountain View, Santa Clara County, California';
    $marker['icon'] = site_url('assets/img/map-ico.png');
    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    // Create the map
    $data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();   

    $this->load->view('jsmap', $data);
```

**Your View seems fine**.

If you still need any clarification don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Try at your end. I think u did not get my point. Google map working fine only issue is not working in tab.

Comment: I did tried it in my local: http://prntscr.com/g6fzt6
I didn't had your icon asset so that's why its showing your default marker.

Comment: Dear friend use tab. I have already told in question and also in comment.

Comment: Oh sorry, now I got let me look into it.

Comment: I've updated now it's working with tab, have a look on updated answer from start.

Comment: vote up the question so other can be benefited with your answer. Thanks a lot.